# Generating Control Points for a Variable Width Curve

Tags: java, javafx, bezier

OK, so I have an application that uses variable width curves that are attached to nodes, and I got it working just fine with one control point. I am generating the control point myself, depending of the curves location relative to the node it is attached. So that the curve is not curved at all when the angle to the node is either 0, 90, 180, 270 or 360.

Like I said, I am using just one control point, and now I want to add another control point to get a smoother curve.. but I am having trouble comprehending what I am doing wrong here.

Here are the relevant code snippets. Hopefully they are relatively straightforward.

```
// Creates, or "projects" a Vector from the given angle and length
public static Point2D project(double angle, double length) {
    double x = length;
    double y = 0;

    double cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle - 90));
    double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle - 90));

    double newX = x * cos - y * sin;
    double newY = x * sin + y * cos;

    return new Point2D(newX, newY);
}

// Linear interpolation
public static double lerp(double a, double b, double ratio) {
    return a + ratio * (b - a);
}

// Linear interpolation for a line
public static Point2D interpolate(Point2D start, Point2D end, double ratio) {
    double x = lerp(start.getX(), end.getX(), ratio);
    double y = lerp(start.getY(), end.getY(), ratio);
    return new Point2D(x, y);
}

// Generates one (or two) control points for a Bezier Curve
public static PointPair calculateCurveControls(Point2D from, Point2D to, double angle) {

    double curvatureAmount = 0;
    double curvatureDirection = 0;

    if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 45) {
        curvatureDirection = 90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(0, 1, angle / 45);
    }
    if (angle > 45 && angle <= 90) {
        curvatureDirection = 90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(1, 0, (angle - 45) / 45);
    }
    if (angle > 90 && angle <= 135) {
        curvatureDirection = -90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(0, 1, (angle - 90) / 45);
    }
    if (angle > 135 && angle <= 180) {
        curvatureDirection = -90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(1, 0, (angle - 135) / 45);
    }
    if (angle > 180 && angle <= 225) {
        curvatureDirection = 90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(0, 1, (angle - 180) / 45);
    }
    if (angle > 225 && angle <= 270) {
        curvatureDirection = 90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(1, 0, (angle - 225) / 45);
    }
    if (angle > 270 && angle <= 315) {
        curvatureDirection = -90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(0, 1, (angle - 270) / 45);
    }
    if (angle > 315 && angle <= 360) {
        curvatureDirection = -90;
        curvatureAmount = lerp(1, 0, (angle - 315) / 45);
    }

    double distance = from.distance(to);

    // Only one control point, this works just fine!
    // Point2D midpoint = interpolate(from, to, 0.5);
    // Point2D c1 = project(angle + curvatureDirection + 180, curvatureAmount * (distance * 0.15f));
    //  c1 = c1.add(midpoint);
    // Point2D c2 = new Point2D(c1.getX(), c1.getY());

    // An attempt to generate two control points
    Point2D first = interpolate(from, to, 0.25);
    Point2D second = interpolate(from, to, 0.75);

    Point2D c1 = project(angle + curvatureDirection + 180, curvatureAmount * (distance * 0.15));
    c1 = c1.add(first);

    Point2D c2 = project(angle + curvatureDirection + 180, curvatureAmount * (distance * 0.15));
    c2 = c2.add(second);

    return new PointPair(c1, c2);
}
```

I've created some visual aids in my app to display the control points and the straight line for the curve... but I still cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.. the control points look like they are in correct position whatever the angle of the curve.

I have a hunch that I am doing something wrong in the "rendering" part of the code, which however works just fine when I use just one control point (i.e. both control points are the same). It is here:

```
// A method from a custom Curve class, which uses a Path to render a variable width curve

public void set(Point2D from, Point2D to) {
            path.getElements().clear();

            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;

            if (developerMode) {
                line.setStartX(from.getX());
                line.setStartY(from.getY());

                line.setEndX(to.getX());
                line.setEndY(to.getY());
            }

            double angle = Utils.angle(from, to);

            Point2D leftStart = Utils.project(angle - 90, thicknessStart / 2);
            leftStart = leftStart.add(from);
            MoveTo moveLeftStart = new MoveTo();
            moveLeftStart.setX(leftStart.getX());
            moveLeftStart.setY(leftStart.getY());

            Point2D leftEnd = Utils.project(angle - 90, thicknessEnd / 2);
            leftEnd = leftEnd.add(to);
            MoveTo moveLeftEnd = new MoveTo();
            moveLeftEnd.setX(leftEnd.getX());
            moveLeftEnd.setY(leftEnd.getY());

            Point2D rightStart = Utils.project(angle + 90, thicknessStart / 2);
            rightStart = rightStart.add(from);
            MoveTo moveRightStart = new MoveTo();
            moveRightStart.setX(rightStart.getX());
            moveRightStart.setY(rightStart.getY());

            Point2D rightEnd = Utils.project(angle + 90, thicknessEnd / 2);
            rightEnd = rightEnd.add(to);
            MoveTo moveRightEnd = new MoveTo();
            moveRightEnd.setX(rightEnd.getX());
            moveRightEnd.setY(rightEnd.getY());

            Utils.PointPair cc1 = Utils.calculateCurveControls(leftStart, leftEnd, angle);

            CubicCurveTo curveLeft = new CubicCurveTo();
            curveLeft.setX(leftEnd.getX());
            curveLeft.setY(leftEnd.getY());
            curveLeft.setControlX1(cc1.p1.getX());
            curveLeft.setControlY1(cc1.p1.getY());
            curveLeft.setControlX2(cc1.p2.getX());
            curveLeft.setControlY2(cc1.p2.getY());

            if (developerMode) {
                c11.setLayoutX(cc1.p1.getX());
                c11.setLayoutY(cc1.p1.getY());
                c12.setLayoutX(cc1.p2.getX());
                c12.setLayoutY(cc1.p2.getY());
            }

            Utils.PointPair cc2 = Utils.calculateCurveControls(rightStart, rightEnd, angle);

            CubicCurveTo curveRight = new CubicCurveTo();
            curveRight.setX(rightStart.getX());
            curveRight.setY(rightStart.getY());
            curveRight.setControlX1(cc2.p1.getX());
            curveRight.setControlY1(cc2.p1.getY());
            curveRight.setControlX2(cc2.p2.getX());
            curveRight.setControlY2(cc2.p2.getY());

            if (developerMode) {
                c21.setLayoutX(cc2.p1.getX());
                c21.setLayoutY(cc2.p1.getY());
                c22.setLayoutX(cc2.p2.getX());
                c22.setLayoutY(cc2.p2.getY());
            }

            path.getElements().add(moveLeftStart);
            path.getElements().add(curveLeft);
            path.getElements().add(new LineTo(moveRightEnd.getX(), moveRightEnd.getY()));
            path.getElements().add(curveRight);
            path.getElements().add(new LineTo(moveLeftStart.getX(), moveLeftStart.getY()));
        }
```

Here's a screenshot of the wrongly curved curve, the line between the curve, and the control points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncEjy.png

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: welcome to "why Bezier curves are hard". http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working perfectly! The only thing I actually had wrong was that I draw the right curve "upside down", so I simply had to pass the first control point as the second one.